# How to create fields with adjustable sizes?

Tags: python, ctypes

I am creating a struct with a set of fields, I would like to define that some of the fields are as long as the input received is, and others will only exist if an input has been provided for them (otherwise it shall disappear) - so when I print the struct only relevant fields (those that have input or predefined to be printed even if '0') will be printed

```
class Data (Frame):
    _name_ = 'Data'
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [
        ("fc",                      fc),
        ("duration",          c_uint16),
        ("add1",           c_ubyte * 6),
        ("add2",           c_ubyte * 6),
        ("add3",           c_ubyte * 6),
        ("fb",                c_uint16),
    ]

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        params = {
            'duration': c_uint16(kwargs.get('duration', 0)),
            'add1': address_to_ubyte(kwargs.get('add1', None)),
            'add2': address_to_ubyte(kwargs.get('add2', None)),
            'add3': address_to_ubyte(kwargs.get('add4', None)),
            'fb':c_uint16(kwargs.get(fb, 0)),
        }
```

This is what I have in the meantime. (I know it doesn't work)
I would like for example for duration add1 and add2 fields to be "0" unless defined otherwise, for add3 to exist only if received input (if not - it shouldn't appear at all) and for "fb" field to be the size of the input given (if not then it should be "0")

Comment: your question is unclear. What do you want to do and what is the desired output exactly? Please read [how to ask a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I have a function that prints the data.
I would like duration, add1 and add2 to be set as '0' unless the program receives and input to that field (with a set size).
add3, how I can define that this is a field just like add1 and add2 only now if there is no input to add3 it shouldn't be at all (not even "0") so when I print the "data" I won't have any additional zeros from add3.
fb field: I would like to to exist no matter what (i.e. if no input is given then it should be "0") but that the size of the field should change according to the input (and not be set such as the other fields)

Comment: Do you have an example of your struct initialization and how it should be and how it is? Also what are *Frame* and *address\_to\_ubyte*? Please **carefully read** [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your question accordingly.